# Best place to store company address

Tags: options, settings-api

Ok I'm creating a site for a company, this company will have multiple users. In the footer I am trying to include the company name, phone and address but not as a widget. I need to store the information in a place where all users can edit it.

In the past I've stored this kind of information in a users profile but that is only good on a single user blog.

Where can I store this information where I can easily pick it up in the theme and all users can see/edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Option Page and name it something like "Adress". In Google you will find a lot about Option Pages. For this small Settings, i would **not** recommend to use a option-framework.

Some Links: [Nettuts](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/create-a-settings-page-for-your-wordpress-theme/) or [12 how to's](http://www.webanddesigners.com/12-tutorials-to-build-your-own-wordpress-theme-option-page/).

Comment: `manage_options` normally is a cap only assigned to admins...

Comment: @kaiser then give non admins also the rights. Easly made through the [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/).

Comment: @mnewmedia - I think the point is that you might not want to give all company users that permission. Otherwise they can access all options, and install & activate plugins.

Comment: @mnewmedia `manage_options` is like a `AAA`-pass. You surely don't want to give any user this capability.

Comment: @kaiser maybe not the right for `manage_options` but the right to edit the Options Page -> for me it works great

Comment: @mnewmedia And what "right" would this be if not the `manage_options` capability? Hint: What you call a "right" is just another name for "capability".

Answer (score 0):

This is direct copy and paste from my `functions.php` using the prefix `rl`.

Hope this helps you. You can just do a if `current_user_can` if you want only admins to see this field and if true run `rl_register_settings_area()`.

```
/**
 * Adds a settings section to general settings in WordPress admin.
 * @return null
 */
function rl_register_settings_area() {

    add_settings_section( 'rl_settings_section', get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . ' Settings', 'rl_setting_prepended_text', 'general');

    add_settings_field( 'rl_setting_address1', 'Address', 'rl_create_settings_field', 'general', 'rl_settings_section' );

    register_setting( 'general', 'rl_setting_address1' );
    register_setting( 'general', 'rl_setting_address2' );
    register_setting( 'general', 'rl_setting_address3' );
    register_setting( 'general', 'rl_setting_address4' );
    register_setting( 'general', 'rl_setting_address5' );

}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'rl_register_settings_area' );


function rl_create_settings_field() {
    ?> 
    <form>
        <input name="rl_setting_address1" type="text" value="<?php echo get_option('rl_setting_address1'); ?>" class="code"  /> <br />
        <input name="rl_setting_address2" type="text" value="<?php echo get_option('rl_setting_address2'); ?>" class="code"  /> <br />
        <input name="rl_setting_address3" type="text" value="<?php echo get_option('rl_setting_address3'); ?>" class="code"  /> <br />
        <input name="rl_setting_address4" type="text" value="<?php echo get_option('rl_setting_address4'); ?>" class="code"  /> <br />
        <input name="rl_setting_address5" type="text" value="<?php echo get_option('rl_setting_address5'); ?>" class="code"  /> <br />
    </form>
    <?php

}

function rl_setting_prepended_text() {

    echo 'Change address of your company';

}
```

Comment: I accept that this might not be the best way to do it.